# make an image bigger on click, and go back to small on second click

Tags: jquery, resize

I have made this jQuery which make all my img bigger when I click a button, but I don't know how to make them go back to the original size when I click that same button again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#changesize").click(function(){
                         $("img").animate({
                             height: "500px",
                             width:  "500px"
                         },50);
            });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some ways to do it with jQuery, you can do it with like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var small={width: "200px",height: "116px"};
        var large={width: "400px",height: "232px"};
        var count=1; 
        $("#imgtab").css(small).on('click',function () { 
            $(this).animate((count==1)?large:small);
            count = 1-count;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgtab" class='small' src="http://www.stories4kid.com/313667_195.jpg">
```

You can also use `toggleClass`
[(info here)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) it is good option too.

example:

```js
$('#imgtab').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('fullSize');
});
```

```css
img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 116px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;
}

.fullSize {
    height: 250px;
    width: 232px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgtab" src="http://www.stories4kid.com/313667_195.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! The only thing is that I want to clic on a button to make the img bigger/smaller and not the actual img ;)

Comment: Thanks the toggle thing works perfectly !:) Would you know how to toggle the class with small img automaticly passed 1000px width for exemple?

Comment: did you see what i post to you ?

Comment: yes the toggleclass works thanks :) But do you know if theres a way to toggle the small img class when the screen width is smaller than 1000px for exemple?

Comment: yes you can use:
if(screen.width < 1000){
$("#button").on('click',function ()....
}

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works so I made a test: when screen is smaller than 1000px it automaticly toggle my big img toggleclass,I tryed this line but it isnt working

Comment: if(screen.width < 1000){ 
             $("img").toggleClass('imgbig');
          }

Comment: I just want to understand how it work so then I can make it myself;) like how to trigger the a toggleClass automaticly(without on clic) when screen is smaller than 1000px, thanks for helping me btw !!

Comment: I can't get it to work :/ I made this jsfiddle so you can see my code,dont look at the result,not working cause I havnt write it all! https://jsfiddle.net/vpm4ws85/

Comment: i think you can not do it this way because there isnt a "while" loop that checks every second what is the screen size, i suggest you to use css properties, and some responsive ways to do it... you can read about it: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp -> nice explantion.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is... :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var small={width: "200px",height: "116px"};
        var large={width: "400px",height: "232px"};
        var count=1; 

        $("#button").on('click',function () { 
            $(imgtab).animate((count==1)?large:small);
            count = 1-count;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgtab" class='small' src="http://www.stories4kid.com/313667_195.jpg" style=width:100px;height:100px>

<button id='button'>
click me
</button>
```